# ReactJS and Express with Axios returning 404

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, react-redux, axios

Not sure what's going on with my code, but I'm trying to just do a test run with axios console logging something out, but I'm getting a 404.

```
class SubscribeForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.emailChange = this.emailChange.bind(this);
    this.emailSubmit = this.emailSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  emailChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  emailSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/subscribe', {
      email: 'someemail@email.com',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      }
    }).then(res => {
      if(res.data.success) {
        this.setState({email: ''})
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log('Error', error.message);
      }
      console.log(error.config);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.subFormSection}>
        <p className={classes.formHelper}>
          Join the club, enter your email address
        </p>

        <form method="post" className={classes.subFormWrap} onSubmit={this.emailSubmit}>
          <TextField
            value = {this.state.value}
            onChange = {this.emailChange}
          />
          <Button
            className={classes.button}
            type="submit"
          >
            Send
            <Icon className={classes.rightIcon}>send</Icon>
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding headers into axios to see if thats the issue, but i don't think it is (or perhaps I'm doing it wrong).

Also, I don't have a /subscribe file, I don't think I need one? Since, I'm capturing it with express here:

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

app.post("/subscribe", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.email);
});
```

This file is within my server files, while the react portion is within client files. I have proxy set up, so when I have run the server, front end and back end is talking to each other.

---

**Updated 404 status turned (pending)**

I also have set up proxy middleware in my client folder `setupProxy.js`

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/subscribe", {
    target: "http://localhost:5000"
  }));
};
```

I'm getting in the request header in my network request for `/subscrib`:

```
Provisional headers are shown
```

Is this causing it to be (pending)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, it seem your server and client app run on different ports. If that is the case you cannot do this:

```
axios.post('/subscribe', {
      email: 'someemail@email.com',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      }
})
```

You are using the path `/subscribe` without a host. Axios tries to use the host from which your client app is running and it doesn't find that path hence the `404` status code.

If this is the case, you can fix it by using the host and port of your server before the `/subscribe` path. See below:

```
axios.post('localhost:4000/subscribe', {
      email: 'someemail@email.com',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      }
})
```

Kindly change the port here `localhost:4000` to your server port.

> Note: This is for your local development only.

If you plan on deploying the app, you might want to use `process.env.PORT` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I set up an http-proxy-middleware, and I connected the route to my server's localhost port.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting a status "pending" now. I know this isn't part of the question, but do you have any idea why its not giving me a correct status?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the proxy code. This helped me connect the server and client side, but now I'm getting an pending status on my /subscribe. I also have `Provisional headers are shown` in network request. could this be an issue?

Comment: It seem more like you are not sending a response back to the client in that case it pends. You have just `console.log(req.body.email)` in your `/subscribe` route. Use `res.send(...)` to send back a response.

Comment: Ohh! awesome! thank you!! yeah, I'm getting a 200 status now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser's inspect element to check if request is made properly(Inspect Element > Network).

By looking at code I think you are missing base url.

it should be like

```
axios.post(baseul + port + request url)
```

Example:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/subscribe')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. my error is calling that out: `POST http://localhost:3000/subscribe 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @hellomello error says localhost:3000 which means it is trying to connect with port 3000. If you're trying to connect with express on a different port, then make sure it's calling the correct port as well.

Comment: @Fawaz this comment made me realize that I had to setup a proxy especially for `/subscribe`. I had already done so with other routes, but forgot I needed to set it up with this one! Thanks!

Comment: @hellomello Happy it helped!